# Shell script for search and copy file type with date in name

Tags: shell, search, scripting, copy

Hi I am working on a script which will search for a particular date pattern in their name and copy them to another location.
Eg. in "w" directory i have files with dates in their names

```
*20130822*
*20130823*
.
.
.
*20130828*
```

All i want is i can give starting date and would like script to copy files for next 7 days from that starting date.
can you suggest me a script which will find these files and copy in a dedicated directory.

```
#!/bin/bash

dt=`date +%Y%m%d`
echo $dt
dt_to_be_checked=`date +%Y%m%d --date='13 days ago'`
echo $dt_to_be_checked

if test $dt -eq $`date +%Y%m%d`
then
  find /cygdrive/w/ -mtime -13 -name "*$dt*" | xargs cp 
  "_$dt_to_be_checked_$dt_to_be_checked" /cygdrive/c/KPI/;
fi
```

Please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you've attempted seems pretty different from the problem you've described.  If you want to generate dates for the next n days given a start date, use a loop:

```
start="20130801"
for i in {1..7}; do 
  date +%Y%m%d --date="+${i} days ${start}"
done
```

Upon executing the above bit, you'd get:

```
20130802
20130803
20130804
20130805
20130806
20130807
20130808
```

Comment: hey Dev the result you have provided may help me.

Comment: what if i want to print it in form of 
cp -av /cygdrive/w/*20130822* /cygdrive/w/*20130823* /cygdrive/w/*20130824* /cygdrive/w/*20130825* /cygdrive/w/*20130826* /cygdrive/w/*20130827* /cygdrive/w/*20130828* /cygdrive/c/KPI/test/;